# saving a restangular object under its "other" id

Tags: restangular

I have a REST service for user accounts:

```
REST_URL/accounts/{:id}
```

when I'm logged in, I can get my own account's information with

```
REST_URL/accounts/me
```

this returns some json like

```
{'id': 4, 'name': 'John'}
```

now when I edit the name and save it, it is posted to

```
REST_URL/accounts/4
```

but I'd like it to be posted to

```
REST_URL/accounts/me
```

with the content

```
{'id': 4, 'name': 'Johnny'}
```

Is this possible? I don't want to send {'id': 'me', 'name': 'Johnny'} because 'id' is numeric on the server.

Here is the js code:

```
Restangular.one('account', 'me').get().then(function(data) {
    $scope.account = data;
});
```

and

```
$scope.account.put();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as nice, but perhaps you could use customPUT?

```
Restangular.one('account', 'me')
.customPUT({ 'id': 4, 'name': 'Jonny'  })
.then(function(data) {
    // success
});
```